# How to use javascript_include_tag to get all scripts in a folder ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use a javascript_link_tag to access a javascript file in a folder. Here is the path:

app/assets/javscripts/ntc.js

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Use the assets pipeline (Sprockets). http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: While you could use 'Dir.glob' and loop through the files it's better to use the built in assets pipeline that can concatenate the files together for performance

Answer (score 1):

Since the file exist inside `assets/javascript` you can add in `application.html.erb` as follows:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "ntc" %>
# => <script src="/assets/ntc.js"></script>
```

if you want to specify from other folder path then u can use as below:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "xmlhr", host: "localhost", protocol: "https" %>
# => <script src="https://localhost/assets/xmlhr.debug-1284139606.js"></script>
```

As @Max mentioned, you can use asset pipeline to include controller specific stylesheets and JavaScript files only in their respective controllers.

If you have a folder of script files and want to load all for a particular controller for example:

```
assets
| 
|___ javascript
        |
        |___ ntc.js
        |
        |___ ntc
              |__script1.js
              |__script2.js
```

Then you can require these files inside `ntc.js` as follows:

```
 //= require ntc/script1
 //= require ntc/script2
```

And can use

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

for more information refer this [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag)

Comment: That only includes a single file.